# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.UUID exception with cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I have a spring boot java application that talks to cassandra .
However one of my queries is failing .

```
 public class ParameterisedListItemRepository {
    
        private PreparedStatement findByIds;
    
        public ParameterisedListItemRepository(Session session, Validator validator, ParameterisedListMsisdnRepository parameterisedListMsisdnRepository ) {
            this.findByIds =  session.prepare("SELECT * FROM mep_parameterisedListItem WHERE id IN ( :ids )");
    
    
    }
    public List<ParameterisedListItem> findAll(List<UUID> ids){
        
        List<ParameterisedListItem> parameterisedListItemList = new ArrayList<>();

        BoundStatement stmt =this.findByIds.bind();
        stmt.setList("ids", ids);
        session.execute(stmt)
            .all()
            .stream()
            .map(parameterisedListItemMapper)
            .forEach(parameterisedListItemList::add);
        return parameterisedListItemList;
    }
    }
```

the following is the stack trace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.UUID
    at com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec$AbstractUUIDCodec.serialize(TypeCodec.java:1626)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractData.setList(AbstractData.java:358)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractData.setList(AbstractData.java:374)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.BoundStatement.setList(BoundStatement.java:681)
    at com.openmind.primecast.repository.ParameterisedListItemRepository.findAll(ParameterisedListItemRepository.java:128)
    at com.openmind.primecast.repository.ParameterisedListItemRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$46ffc15e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.openmind.primecast.repository.ParameterisedListItemRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2db3c41.findAll(<generated>)
    at com.openmind.primecast.service.impl.ParameterisedListItemServiceImpl.findByParameterisedList(ParameterisedListItemServiceImpl.java:102)
    at com.openmind.primecast.web.rest.ParameterisedListItemResource.getParameterisedListItemsByParameterisedList(ParameterisedListItemResource.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Any idea what is going wrong. I know this query is the problem

```
SELECT * FROM mep_parameterisedListItem WHERE id IN ( :ids )
```

any idea how I can change the findAll function to achieve the query?

this is the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE "Openmind".mep_parameterisedlistitem (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    data text,
    msisdn text,
    ordernumber int,
    parameterisedlist uuid
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the table schema, my guess is that a change was made to the table so the schema no longer match the bindings in the prepared statement.

A big part of the problem is your query with `SELECT *`. Our recommendation for best practice is to *explicitly* name all the columns you're retrieving from the table. By specifying the columns in your query, you avoid surprises when the table schema changes.

In this instance, either a new column was added or an old column was dropped. With the cached prepared statement, it was expecting one column type and got another -- the `ArrayList` doesn't match `UUID`.

The solution is to re-prepare the statement and name all the columns. Cheers!

Comment: CREATE TABLE "Openmind".mep_parameterisedlistitem (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    data text,
    msisdn text,
    ordernumber int,
    parameterisedlist uuid
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE

Comment: this is the table definiton CREATE TABLE "Openmind".mep_parameterisedlistitem (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    data text,
    msisdn text,
    ordernumber int,
    parameterisedlist uuid
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE